# adding multiple views in your app

Tags: objective-c

I am working on an app in which the starting point is a map and it has a button too. What i want is that if user clicks the button it will take him to another view which just have two or three buttons or other elements.

Please provide me with detail answer so that i would be able to do it.

Thanks in advance, i would really appreciate it.

Comment: Be more specific with how you want that transition to happen, and do you want to be able to go back? Do you want it to slide up from the bottom, or down from the top? Would you rather it slide to the side? No animation? What? Be specific or we can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your application uses the UINavigationController, this will do the trick. Make sure you #import your other view's controller file in your header. The below example assumes your controller is named ViewSettings.

```
- (void)gotoOtherview {
    ViewSettings *settings = [[ViewSettings alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewSettings" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:settings animated:YES];
}
```